# Unable to locate package libtcnative-1:i386

Tags: apt, 32-bit, libraries

I need libtcnative-1:i386, an x86 library, but I'm working in Ubuntu Desktop x64 20.04.1.
I tried to get it from default apt reposiory but it fails.

How can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

32 bit is no longer supported on later versions of Ubuntu.  And only a **very small subset** of packages are whitelisted to stay on i386 in terms of being built and supported.  In 20.04, `libtcnative-1` is not built on i386.  If your application / library does not work with the `amd64` libraries, then the application needs to be reprogrammed to work properly with the `amd64` version of the libs.'

You could attempt to install the version from Bionic by downloading the `.deb` for it and try installing it, but I'm pretty sure it won't install if the dependencies are missing, too.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a thirdparty native library only of 32bit version, the maintainer doesn't provide source or 64bit build. Then I will be stuck for future versions, is there any chance to create a 32-64bit wrapper for native libraries?

Comment: @Tobia Unlikely.  If the maintainer doesn't provide 64-bit source then you'll likely need to either go back to using 18.04 (or use an 18.04 VM or container), or attempt to download and install the Bionic library and dependencies yourself by hand - can't guarantee you'll get all the deps you need though and that's going to send you through Dependency Hell if you can't find all the deps in i386 library formats.